# Combination of numbers to fit threshold

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a set (or a list) of numbers {1, 2.25, 5.63, 2.12, 7.98, 4.77} and i want to find the best combination of numbers from this set/list which when added are closest to 10.

How do i accomplish that in python using an element from collection ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 1):

If the problem size permits, you can use some friends in `itertools` to quickly brute force through it:

```
s = {1, 2.25, 5.63, 2.12, 7.98, 4.77}
from itertools import combinations, chain
res = min(((comb, abs(sum(comb)-10)) for comb in chain(*[combinations(s, k) for k in range(1, len(s)+1)])), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
print res
```

Output:

```
(2.25, 5.63, 2.12)
```

Comment: Didn't know the combination package. i like it !

Answer (score 0):

It's an NP-Hard problem. If your data are not too big, you can just test every single solution with a code like :

```
def combination(itemList):
    """ Returns all the combinations of items in the list """
    def wrapped(current_pack, itemList):
        if itemList == []:
            return [current_pack]
        else:
            head, tail = itemList[0], itemList[1:]
            return wrapped(current_pack+[head], tail) + wrapped(current_pack, tail)
    return wrapped([], itemList)

def select_best(combination_list, objective):
    """ Returns the element whose the sum of its own elements is the nearest to the objective"""
    def element_sum(combination):
        result = 0.0
        for element in combination:
            result+= element
        return result

    best, weight = combination_list[0], element_sum(combination_list[0])

    for combination in combination_list:
        current_weight =  element_sum(combination)
        if (abs(current_weight-objective) < abs(weight-objective)):
            best, weight = combination, current_weight

    return best


if __name__ == "__main__" : 
    items = [1, 2.25, 5.63, 2.12, 7.98, 4.77]

    combinations = combination(items)
    combinations.sort()
    print(combinations, len(combinations))#2^6 combinations -> 64

    best = select_best(combinations, 10.0)
    print(best)
```

This code will give you the better solution whatever input you give to it. But as you can see the number of combination is 2^n where n is the number of element in your list. Try this with more than 50 element and say good bye to your RAM memory. As perfectly correct from an algorithmic point of view, you can wait for more than you're entire life to get a response for real case problems. Metaheuristic and Constraint satisfaction problem algorithms could be useful for more efficient approach.